# Proper ORDER BY query for items based on associated items in the same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to rank a list of bundled products (each bundle is a singular item in the table) that is based on the aggregate number of its individual components (which are each singular items in the same table) sold.

So I have a table of products that contain both a main item and its associated components in the same table. There is a column that identifies it as a main item or component (main='1' or main='0') as well as a column that associates components to the main item's row ID (master_id='xxx'). I also have a column that keeps track of how many are sold (column is called sold_count).

But how do I sort the resulting query of the main items by the total number of sold_count of the all the associated components of each main item?

```
SELECT Item_Name FROM 'products' WHERE main='1' ORDER BY _______________ ???
```

Here is the table structure:

```
    ID | Item_Name | Main | Master_ID | Sold_Count
    1    Kit A         1       0          0
    2    Widget A1     0       1          3
    3    Widget A2     0       1          6
    4    Kit B         1       0          0
    5    Widget B1     0       4          2
    6    Widget B2     0       4          8
```

So I would want to have Kit A and Kit B sorted based on the number of the associated widgets sold. So the sort should be:

1. Kit B
2. Kit A

Because Kit B had 10 widget components sold, while Kit A only had 9 total.

Comment: You need an aggregate, then you sort by the aggregate.

Comment: Do you mean I need to make two separate queries first?

Comment: Also use backticks for column and table names FROM \`products\`

Comment: you can post an example in sqlfiddle? sometimes while making the query in fiddle your doubt is gone

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the result you want probably

This is without using mysql extension to group by and uses a varchar field to group by

```
 SELECT b.item_name, 
       Sum(a.sold_count) AS sales 
FROM   products AS a 
       INNER JOIN products AS b 
               ON a.master_id = b.id 
GROUP  BY b.id
ORDER  BY Sum(a.sold_count) DESC
```

if you want to use the mysql extension and group by an int field

SqlFiddle example http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1725c/4/0

Comment: group by id(int) instead of item_name(varchar)

Comment: Done, thanks, but I am still not sure its fully acceptable to group by a field other than those in select list

Comment: as long as the id and the item_name are one-to-one, it is fine.

Comment: This is non-standard `GROUP BY`. I would recommend *against* using MySQL's extension.